# Running a custom function in a Server Component using Next JS App Router at runtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have the following server component `Home` that calls the function `getMyAge`:

```js
// app/page.tsx
import { getMyAge } from './utils/datetime';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Page>
      <Paragraph>I'm {getMyAge()} years old</Paragraph>
    </Page>
  );
}
```

```js
// app/utils/datetime.ts
export function getMyAge() {
  const today = new Date();
  const birthDate = new Date(1997, 1, 17);

  const yearDifference = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
  const monthDifference = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
  const dayDifference = today.getDate() - birthDate.getDate();

  if (monthDifference < 0 || (monthDifference === 0 && dayDifference < 0)) {
    return yearDifference - 1;
  } else {
    return yearDifference;
  }
}
```

It runs fine in development, but after I generate the static build for production, the result of getMyAge does not change. I see that as the side is generated statically, the function only runs at build time. How do I make it run at runtime, when the user requests the page?

Thanks.

By looking at Next Docs, I saw that `getServerSideProps` could do the trick, but the exemples using App Router all seemed to involve the revalidate option of their extension on the fetch API, which I do not require. Is there a way to achieve this without resorting to a client component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Next.js caches pages by default on production with the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router. If you want a dynamic rendering per request, similar to `getServerSideProps`, use the [`dynamic`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#dynamic) config option:

> `'force-dynamic'`: Force dynamic rendering, which will result in routes being rendered for each user at request time. This option is equivalent to `getServerSideProps()` in the pages directory.

```
// app/page.tsx

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic"; // 

import { getMyAge } from "./utils/datetime";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Page>
      <Paragraph>I'm {getMyAge()} years old</Paragraph>
    </Page>
  );
}
```